# How to pass arguments/parameters with button clicks into functions?

Tags: jquery, html, parameters

I have a simple function that is supposed to display either of two sets of data in a HTML table. This data comes from an external domain using an ajax request. Both sets of data have been parsed and are stored in two variables, named `animalData` and `fruitNvegData`.

I have two buttons which run the `buildTable()` function. I need to make each button pass the relevant data into the function. I know how to do this in JavaScript but that way doesn't work with jQuery. I have read many examples of passing arguments/parameters into a function but none of the methods work for me. I have tried a few variations on this kind of thing, but no joy:

```
$("animalButton").click({ param: animalData }, buildTable);
```

For now I am using `animalData` in the `each()` loop to make sure everything else is working. I have found many similar questions here on StackOverflow, but none of these work either. Like using `bind()` for instance.

This is my entire jquery code.  So how do I pass the relevant data with each button click into the function?

```
  var animalData;  
  var fruitNvegData;

  $(document).ready(function() {

          $.ajax({
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url:   "http://www.adweb.agency/interview/api/animals",
                  type:  'get',
                  success:  function (data) {

                           animalData = $.parseJSON(data);

                         },

                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("animal data unavailable at this time");
                        }
                });

           $.ajax({
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url:   "http://www.adweb.agency/interview/api/fruitveg",
                  type:  'get',
                  success:  function (data) {

                            fruitNvegData = $.parseJSON(data);   

                        },

                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Fruit n Veg data unavailable at this time");
                        }
                });
         });


 function buildTable(){       

                         var i = 0;
                         var table = '<table class="mainTable"><tr><th>item</th><th>image</th><th>description</th></tr>';

                               $.each(animalData, function (idx, obj) {                                   
                                        table += ('<tr>');
                                        table += ('<td>' + obj.Title + '</td>');
                                        table += ('<td><img src="' + obj.ImageURLs.Thumb + '"></td>');
                                        table += ('<td>' + obj.Description + '</td>');
                                        table += ('</tr>');
                                  });

                     table += '</table>';
                    $("#tableContainer").html(table);
    };


     $("#animalButton").click(buildTable);

     $("#fruitNvegButton").click(buildTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is accessing your two variables whilst keeping the code simple. The easiest way to do this is to join your two variables, `animalData` and `fruitNvegData` into a single object.

You can then reference those variables via the keys of this parent object, which you can add to their respective buttons as `data` attributes. This then allows you to add a common class to those buttons and use a single event handler for both, something like this:

```
<div id="tableContainer"></div>

<button class="buildTable" data-key="animal">Populate animal table</button>
<button class="buildTable" data-key="fruitnveg">Populate animal table</button>
```

```js
var data = {
    'animal': animalData,
    'fruitnveg': fruitNvegData
}

function buildTable() {
    var table = '<table class="mainTable"><tr><th>item</th><th>image</th><th>description</th></tr>';
    $.each(data[$(this).data('key')], function(idx, obj) {
        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.Title + '</td>';
        table += '<td><img src="' + obj.ImageURLs.Thumb + '"></td>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.Description + '</td>';
        table += '</tr>';
    });
    table += '</table>';
    $("#tableContainer").html(table);
};

$(".buildTable").click(buildTable);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/LveacuLm/)

Comment: That's a lot for me to take in. Excellent and comprehensively answered. I shall test it now.

Comment: No problems. Let me know if you need anything clarifying

Comment: Which stored variables? If you mean the two `..Data` vars, then they're added to the `data` object.

Comment: How do I join the two variables, animalData and fruitNvegData into the single object.

Comment: That's what the first line of my JS example above is doing - `var data = {
    'animal': animalData,
    'fruitnveg': fruitNvegData
}`

Comment: I'm slowly absorbing this. I have the buttons displaying the table header but no content. This may be an error somewhere else in my code. I'm on to it.

Comment: I still do not have this working. Could this be caused by me parsing the data before i store it in the variables?

Comment: No - you need to do that. I can't really help without seeing your code. Try updating the working jsFiddle I posted with your code so I can see what you have

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you were getting your data via AJAX on an external domain. If you check the console (press F12) are there any errors on your page about CORS headers? Also your code needs to wait for both requests to complete before it does anything. To do that use `$.when`. Here's an updated version that should work, assuming your requests complete successfully: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/LveacuLm/2/

Comment: Also those URLs return XML, not JSON - which is another issue entirely.

Comment: I have no CORS errors.  It seems like I best edit my question and include my whole code.